# how to check if objects are compatible in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have recently been learning how to use Javascript. However I am having problems trying to accomplish a simple project I am doing for myself. Basically I have a drop down menu which contains Intel and AMD CPUs and another menu which contains GPUs from the same companies. I want the user to be able to select a CPU and a GPU from the lists and the code to say if they are a good match or not compatible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(S1,S2){
    
     var S1 = document.getElementById(S1);
     var S2 = document.getElementById(S2);
     S2.innerHTML = "";
     
     switch(S1.value) {
        case "Intel":
            var optionArray = ["","I7","I5"];
            break;
        case "AMD":
            var optionArray = ["","RX500","RX100"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
     
     for(var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = optionArray[i];
      S2.add(option);
     
     } 
    }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function populate2(S3,S4){
    
     var S3 = document.getElementById(S3);
     var S4 = document.getElementById(S4);
     S4.innerHTML = "";
     
     switch(S3.value) {
        case "Intel":
            var optionArray = ["","GTX1080","GTX1050"];
            break;
        case "AMD":
            var optionArray = ["","RX500","RX100"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
     
     for(var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = optionArray[i];
      S4.add(option);
     
     } 
    }
    </script>
    
    <script>
    function compatable() {
     var S1
     var S4
     var text
     if (S1 == S4) {
            text = "these parts are compatable";
        } else if (S1!= S4) {
            text = "These parts are not compatable";
        } 
    
    
    
    
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick="compatable()">Submit</button>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Pick your CPU</h1>
    <hr />
    Choose Your Brand
     <select id="Select1" name="Select1" onchange="populate(this.id,'Select2')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Intel">Intel</option>
      <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
     </select>
    <hr />
    
    Choose Your Model
     <select id="Select2" name="Select2">
    <hr />
    
    
    <P>Pick your GPU</p>
    <hr />
    Choose Your Brand
    </select>
     <select id="Select3" name="Select3" onchange="populate2(this.id,'Select4')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Intel">Intel</option>
      <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
     </select>
    <hr />
    Choose Your Model
     <select id="Select4" name="Select4">
    <hr />
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So.. is it `compatable` or `comtpatable`? Just make sure you first avoid typo error. And, you have forgotten to add `option.value` when adding the option element dynamically. And `S1` & `S2` in your `comtpatable`, will always be `undefined` since you declared that in the function scope instead of globally. Your question is kinda unclear

Comment: You've been very friendly when telling all this, but what is your question?

Comment: a) what's the question? b) you have a typo in your function name

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot to delete that third function. We can ignore that. Basically my question is, if I pick say a GTX1070 from my dropdown and pair it with say an I3 processor, how do I write the code which will tell my if they are compatible. I'm not sure how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add code sample as executable snippet so that it's faster to identify bugs and people can directly test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a function for choosing the correct compatability test depending on S1.value, then below that is a function for testing if S3.value is compatable with the S1.value.

The example function Compatibility_Test_I7() creates an array which contains the components which are compatible with the I7 and then loops through to see if S3.value are equivalent to any of the objects in the array of compatible components.

```
function Call_Test() {



switch(S1.value) {
    case "I7":
         Compatibility_Test_I7();
        break;
    case "I5":
        Compatibility_Test_I5();
        break;
    case "RX500":
        Compatibility_Test_RX500();
        break;
    case "RX100":
        Compatibility_Test_RX100();
        break;
`       default:
            break;
    }

}




 function Compatibility_Test_I7() {
     var Compatible_I7 = ['GTX1080', 'GTX1050']


    (step = 0; step < 5; step++)
    for (i = 0; i < Compatible_I7.length; i++) {
     if (Compatible_I7(i) == S3.value ) {
        return "Compatible Configuration";
      } else {
        /* Nothing *\
      }
    }
    }
```